# Carrying out the actions of an input type button element in the parent frame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, button

I've an iFrame A which has an iFrame B inside it. In frame B i load a page which has a input type button element. It basically, when gets clicked, navigates to another page. Now i want to change the target of the button so that i loads the page in its parent iFrame A.

I've tried changing

```
currentButton.target = '_parent'
```

But it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Show the script that the button executes.
Most likely onClick="location='somepage.html'" which needs to be parent.iframeA.location='somepage.html'

Comment: So thats what i was trying to say. I cant change the events of the button. I'm loading a page done by some third party person. I want to know whether i can change the target of that button by adding any attribute or something without touching the event or altering its behavior.

Comment: If you can do currentButton.target, you can do currentButton.onclick=function() {... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the page in iframeB is not from your domain, you can only change its behaviour by reading the complete page on the server, modify the behaviour and serve it as if it came from your server.
2. If it comes from your server, then I do not see how you cannot change the behaviour.
   If you cannot do 1) then the answer is "not possible"

Answer (score 0):

The following will do it:

```
parent.location.href = "your url here";
```

Comment: I cant alter the page elements behaivor.

Comment: mplungjan: iframe B's parent is iframe A, so calling that line in iframe B will load the new page into iframe A. Am I missing something?

Comment: Doh. No. I missed the first part of the sentence. Hence my parent.iframeA.location and not parent.location in my first comment

Comment: I've not designed the page that is getting loaded in iFrame B. I cant alter onClick events or whatever it is. I just cant alter the behavior. iFrame B has a input button 'cancel' which is when clicked goes back to a 'source url'. I want to load that source url in iFrame A instead of iFrame B. Hope you get it.